# JavaScript How to create class with two C-Tors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create class with two constractors function, one to set the fields of calss (one by one), and another that get JSON object and convert it to my class object.

this is the code that I write:

```
 var car = function(type,carNumber)
{this.type=type; this.carNumber=carNumber};
```

How is it possible to add another function with a JSON param.
like this:

```
function fromJson(car ) //car is a Json object
{
   //... convert it to car class object
}
```

thank you!

Comment: _convert it to my class object._....... very confusing. what exactly you mean to say? and check for some grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since javascript is loosely typed, one of the ways to do this is by detecting the number of parameters passed in, like

```
function Car() {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        //interpret JSON
    } else if (arguments.length == 2) {
        this.type=arguments[0];
        this.carNumber=arguments[1];
    }
};
```

or you can just use your same code and add

```
function Car(type,carNumber)
{this.type=type; this.carNumber=carNumber};

car.fromJson = function(car)
{
   //... convert it to car class object
}
```